# How can i turn my eye blinking python script into a web application?

Tags: python, opencv, web-applications, face-recognition, face-detection

I have a python script that detects eye blinking using openCV and facial_recongnition, how can i convert it to a web application that i can let others use?
Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just done almost the same project... My advice is to use Flask - a very simple for learning framework. Start from tutorial [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to do it using Flask.

Comment: hi @Bohdan, i took your suggestion and was able to achieve what i needed at the time using Flask, Thank you for that. 
I have a follow up doubt about it, which is, if i want to host this program for the public, where it would make use of the users webcam and do a detection, and return something how would you suggest i could go about it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow. If I uderstood you right, you are talking about access of web-based server app (back-end) to a client's (front-end) web-camera? I have no such exp, so ... you may try this: https://towardsdatascience.com/video-streaming-in-web-browsers-with-opencv-flask-93a38846fe00

Comment: Hi Bohdan, yes that's correct. I have built a program that needs to take input from a users webcam and identify some action, to make sure whether it is an actual person and not an image. So i have this program working on flask, but if i host it, it uses my webcam, because i am the source, i would like the input to be taken from users webcam.  Something like this, https://gradio.app/.